# JSONObject enum values are empty when converted to string

Tags: java

I am trying to add enum value as shown in the code below , when i print the output or convert it to string the enum values are empty. how to resolve this issue

```
package com.test;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class TestJson {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JSONObject json_obj = new JSONObject();
    json_obj.put("name", "paul");

    Map<String,enumObj> a = new HashMap<>();
    a.put("val", enumObj.LOW);

    json_obj.put("json_obj", a);
    System.out.println(json_obj);
}

public enum enumObj{
        LOW,
        MEDIUM,
        HIGH
    }}
```

The output is  as below

{"name":"paul","json_obj":{"val":{}}}

Comment: Your code works fine with java17

{"name":"paul","json_obj":"{val=LOW}"}

Comment: I am not aware of the underlying mechanism, but I think your enums don't represent any values yet. So the program doesn't know how to write them in JSON format. I think this can solve your problems: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-enums.

Comment: @KostasNitaf i am using openjdk18

Comment: even after adding values its still the same    public enum enumObj {
        LOW("LOW"),
        MEDIUM("MEDIUM"),
        HIGH("HIGH");

        private String unit;

        enumObj(String unit) {
            this.unit = unit;
        }
    }

Comment: It works in 18 too. :( 
```import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

class TestJson {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject json_obj = new JSONObject();
        json_obj.put("name", "paul");

        Map<String,enumObj> a = new HashMap<>();
        a.put("val", enumObj.MEDIUM);

        json_obj.put("json_obj", a);
        System.out.println(json_obj);
    }

    public enum enumObj{
        LOW,
        MEDIUM,
        HIGH
    }}```

Answer (score 0):

Try converting `enum` to string.

```
a.put("val", enumObj.LOW.toString());
```

Comment: Tried this , the output is same {"name":"paul","json_obj":{"val":{}}}